# Перезапись циклов | JS

Tags: javascript

Есть массив: arr = [{}, {}, {}]

Мне нужно, чтобы в каждый объект массива, не зависимо от того, массив **arr** ли это или созданный **только что**, записывалось значение его индекса в массиве. Т.е. если я куда-то передам arr[2] и оттуда вызову arrayChild.myIndex, то мне выдаст индекс этого элемента в массиве.

Я думал делать это через Object.defineProperty, но вообще не понимаю, как такое реализовать.

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, ???).

Может как-то переопределять forEach/map/reduce и т.д.? Звучит как плохой вариант.

Ожидаемый результат:

**До внедрения:**

arr = [{}, {}, {}]

arr.map(v => v.myIndex) -> error

**После внедрения скрипта:**

arr = [{}, {}, {}]

arr.map(v => v.myIndex) -> [0, 1, 2]

**UPD:**

```
const arr = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];
arr.forEach((item, i) => {
    Object.defineProperty(item, "myIndex", {
        get: function (){
            return i;
        }
    });
});


console.log("__", arr.map(item => ({
    current: item,
    index: item.myIndex
})));
```

Это работающий пример. Но я четко в вопросе написал, как мне сделать это на фундоментальном уровня (на уровне прототипа). Чтобы не делать для каждого массива forEach/map/и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще не понятно, чего вы хотите. Можете дополнить вопрос конкретными примерами?

Comment: @SwaD добавил кода.

Comment: зачем добавлять `index` как поле объекта, если он приходит тебе в параметре callback у `map`

Answer (score 1):

Через forEach делается очень просто)

```
arr.forEach((el, i) => {el.myIndex = i})
```

1. "el" - очередной элемент в массиве.
2. "i" - индекс этого элемента.
3. "el.myIndex = i" - присваиваем элементу свойство myIndex со значением его индекса.

Answer (score -1):

То, что я пытался сделать не очень хорошо. Почитав статьи в интернете я понял, что таким методом можно сломать вообще весь js на странице. Поэтому я немного поменял условия и добился того, чего хотел:

```
const defineItem = (item, arr, index) => { //Чтобы не дублировать код
     if (!item?.prev) {
         Object.defineProperty(item, "prev", {//Объявляем ключ и устанавливаем только геттер
             get: () => {
                 if (arr[index - 1]) {
                     return arr[index - 1];
                 }
            
                 return null;
            }
        });
    }
    if (!item?.next) {
        Object.defineProperty(item, "next", {
            get: () => {
                if (arr[index + 1]) {
                    return arr[index + 1];
                }
            
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}

//Объявляем новую функцию-итератор
Array.prototype.smartForEach = function (callback) {
    this.forEach((item, index, arr) => { //запускаем стандартный forEach
        defineItem(item, this, index); //определяем для каждого итема в нём новые переменные
        callback(item, index, arr); //вызываем коллбек
    }, this);
} // То же самое для другой функции
Array.prototype.smartMap = function (callback, thisArgs) {
    return this.map((item, index, arr) => {
        defineItem(item, this, index);
        return callback(item, index, arr);
    });
}
```

Теперь в любой точке кода можно создавать или использовать уже созданные массивы по новому:

[image: введите сюда код]

Объяснять для чего это не вижу смысла, т.к. все, кто занимался группировкой больших массивов объектов (с большим количеством ключей, которые нужно учитывать при группировке), сочтут полезным знать в каждой итерации соседние элементы.

Пример такой группировки:

```
const groupArr = [
    {
        isThread: false,
        userID: 0,
        created_at: 0
    },
    {
        isThread: false,
        userID: 1,
        created_at: 1
    },
    {
        isThread: false,
        userID: 1,
        created_at: 2
    },
    {
        isThread: true,
        userID: 0,
        created_at: 3
    },
    {
        isThread: false,
        userID: 0,
        created_at: 4
    },
    {
        isThread: false,
        userID: 3,
        created_at: 18
    },
    {
        isThread: false,
        userID: 0,
        created_at: 19
    },
    {
        isThread: false,
        userID: 4,
        created_at: 41
    },
    {
        isThread: false,
        userID: 0,
        created_at: 42
    },
    {
        isThread: true,
        userID: 0,
        created_at: 51
    },
    {
        isThread: false,
        userID: 0,
        created_at: 61
    },
    {
        isThread: false,
        userID: 0,
        created_at: 71
    },
    {
        isThread: false,
        userID: 0,
        created_at: 72
    }
]
let group = 0;
console.log('_', groupArr.smartMap((item, index) => {
    if (item.prev) {
        let isNewGroup = false;
        if (!isNewGroup) isNewGroup = item.prev.userID !== item.userID;
        if (!isNewGroup) isNewGroup = item.prev.isThread !== item.isThread;
        if (!isNewGroup) isNewGroup = (item.created_at - item.prev.created_at) > 10;
    
        if (isNewGroup) {
            group += 1;
        }
    }
    
    return {
        group: group,
        ...item
    }
}));
```

И получаем идеальный результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Особенно это полезно, когда элемент передается в функцию (React Component к примеру), но не хочется прокидывать весь массив для группировки внутри.

Comment: слишком надуманная проблема. К тому же не всегда возможно изменить объект в массиве и добавить ему свойство. Достаточно было сделать одну функцию с `map` - которая бы вернула нужную структуру, а не пытаться сломать свои собственные данные